# Converting heximal to decimal

Tags: hex, byte

I am trying to parse a BLOB (binary object) from an api.

Supposedly `a0acb90300000000` in hex represents `62500000` in decimal format.

However, when I convert `62500000` to hexadecimal I get `3b9aca0`

I'm not sure what type of conversion it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully putting everything in a code block is okay, it makes things easier to format.

```
a0acb90300000000
Lets add some spaces and capitalize letters:
A0 AC B9 03 00 00 00 00


62500000
Windows calculator converts to:
3B9ACA0
This is a number from a calculator, lets add spaces right to left
3 B9 AC A0
Lets add some zeros to the left side, we have:
00 00 00 00 03 B9 AC A0
Before:
A0 AC B9 03 00 00 00 00
```

Your initial hex blob is in little endian, and is a 64-bit integer, possibly unsigned.

Wikipedia has further reading on: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

The language you're using should have something to unpack that for you.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.